# Using jQuery to color imported SVG

Tags: jquery, html, svg

I'm trying to change the fill color of paths in an imported svg file in an html document using jQuery. To start with, I'm just trying to make Colorado red in a map of the United States. This is the code I have at the moment:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#CO').css('fill', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<object data='states.svg' type='image/svg+xml'></object>
```

An abbreviated version of the states.svg file is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="959" height="593">
<title>Blank US states map</title>
<g id="outlines">
  ...
  ...
  <path id="AZ" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M135.1,389.7 l-0.3,1.5 0.5,1 18.9,10.7 12.1,7.6 14.7,8.6 16.8,10 12.3,2.4 25.4,2.7 6,-39.6 7,-53.1 4.4,-31 -24.6,-3.6 -60.7,-11 -0.2,1.1 -2.6,16.5 -2.1,3.8 -2.8,-0.2 -1.2,-2.6 -2.6,-0.4 -1.2,-1.1 -1.1,0.1 -2.1,1.7 -0.3,6.8 -0.3,1.5 -0.5,12.5 -1.5,2.4 -0.4,3.3 2.8,5 1.1,5.5 0.7,1.1 1.1,0.9 -0.4,2.4 -1.7,1.2 -3.4,1.6 -1.6,1.8 -1.6,3.6 -0.5,4.9 -3,2.9 -1.9,0.9 -0.1,5.8 -0.6,1.6 0.5,0.8 3.9,0.4 -0.9,3 -1.7,2.4 -3.7,0.4z"/>
  <path id="CA" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M122.7,385.9 l-19.7,-2.7 -10,-1.5 -0.5,-1.8 v-9.4 l-0.3,-3.2 -2.6,-4.2 -0.8,-2.3 -3.9,-4.2 -2.9,-4.7 -2.7,-0.2 -3.2,-0.8 -0.3,-1 1.5,-0.6 -0.6,-3.2 -1.5,-2.1 -4.8,-0.8 -3.9,-2.1 -1.1,-2.3 -2.6,-4.8 -2.9,-3.1 h-2.9 l-3.9,-2.1 -4.5,-1.8 -4.2,-0.5 -2.4,-2.7 0.5,-1.9 1.8,-7.1 0.8,-1.9 v-2.4 l-1.6,-1 -0.5,-2.9 -1.5,-2.6 -3.4,-5.8 -1.3,-3.1 -1.5,-4.7 -1.6,-5.3 -3.2,-4.4 -0.5,-2.9 0.8,-3.9 h1.1 l2.1,-1.6 1.1,-3.6 -1,-2.7 -2.7,-0.5 -1.9,-2.6 -2.1,-3.7 -0.2,-8.2 0.6,-1.9 0.6,-2.3 0.5,-2.4 -5.7,-6.3 v-2.1 l0.3,-0.5 0.3,-3.2 -1.3,-4 -2.3,-4.8 -2.7,-4.5 -1.8,-3.9 1,-3.7 0.6,-5.8 1.8,-3.1 0.3,-6.5 -1.1,-3.6 -1.6,-4.2 -2.7,-4.2 0.8,-3.2 1.5,-4.2 1.8,-0.8 0.3,-1.1 3.1,-2.6 5.2,-11.8 0.2,-7.4 1.69,-4.9 38.69,11.8 25.6,6.6 -8,31.3 -8.67,33.1 12.63,19.2 42.16,62.3 17.1,26.1 -0.4,3.1 2.8,5.2 1.1,5.4 1,1.5 0.7,0.6 -0.2,1.4 -1.4,1 -3.4,1.6 -1.9,2.1 -1.7,3.9 -0.5,4.7 -2.6,2.5 -2.3,1.1 -0.1,6.2 -0.6,1.9 1,1.7 3,0.3 -0.4,1.6 -1.4,2 -3.9,0.6z m-73.9,-48.9 1.3,1.5 -0.2,1.3 -3.2,-0.1 -0.6,-1.2 -0.6,-1.5z m1.9,0 1.2,-0.6 3.6,2.1 3.1,1.2 -0.9,0.6 -4.5,-0.2 -1.6,-1.6z m20.7,19.8 1.8,2.3 0.8,1 1.5,0.6 0.6,-1.5 -1,-1.8 -2.7,-2 -1.1,0.2 v1.2z m-1.4,8.7 1.8,3.2 1.2,1.9 -1.5,0.2 -1.3,-1.2 c0,0 -0.7,-1.5 -0.7,-1.9 0,-0.4 0,-2.2 0,-2.2z"/>
  <path id="CO" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M380.2,235.5 l-36,-3.5 -79.1,-8.6 -2.2,22.1 -7,50.4 -1.9,13.7 34,3.9 37.5,4.4 34.7,3 14.3,0.6z"/>
  <path id="CT" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M852,190.9 l3.6,-3.2 1.9,-2.1 0.8,0.6 2.7,-1.5 5.2,-1.1 7,-3.5 -0.6,-4.2 -0.8,-4.4 -1.6,-6 -4.3,1.1 -21.8,4.7 0.6,3.1 1.5,7.3 v8.3 l-0.9,2.1 1.7,2.2z"/>
  <path id="DE" fill="#D3D3D3" d="M834.4,247.2 l-1,0.5 -3.6,-2.4 -1.8,-4.7 -1.9,-3.6 -2.3,-1 -2.1,-3.6 0.5,-2 0.5,-2.3 0.1,-1.1 -0.6,0.1 -1.7,1 -2,1.7 -0.2,0.3 1.4,4.1 2.3,5.6 3.7,16.1 5,-0.3 6,-1.1z"/>
  ...
  ...
</g>
<path id="frames" fill="none" stroke="#A9A9A9" stroke-width="2" d="M215,493v55l36,45 M0,425h147l68,68h85l54,54v46"/>
</svg>
```

When I open the page, Colorado is still gray. Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are loading the SVG via an `<object>`. jQuery can't find the Colorado element because it is hidden inside the DOM.

You need to wait for the `<object>` to load the SVG and then access the embedded SVG via the `contentDocument` property on the object.

```
<object id=:map" data='states.svg' type='image/svg+xml'>
</object>


// Wait for the SVG to load...
window.onload = function() {
  // Get the object by id
  var map = document.getElementById("map");
  // Get the SVG document inside the object element
  var svgDoc = map.contentDocument;
  // Get the state
  var colorado = svgDoc.getElementById("CO");
  // Change its colour
  colorado.setAttribute("fill", "red");
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<script> $( document ).ready(function()       { $('#CO').css('fill', '#ff0000'); }); </script>
```

Or this:

```
<script> $( document ).ready(function() { $('#CO').css({fill: '#ff0000'}); }); </script>
```